# kpsewhich not found when installing texlive

Tags: kpsewhich

On arch linux.
This results in having no pdflatex command

```
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                    [#########################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                  [#########################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                       [#########################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                 [#########################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                               [#########################################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling texlive-core                                                                   [#########################################################] 100%
>>> updmap custom entries should go into /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap-local.cfg
>>> fmtutil custom entries should go into /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil-local.cnf
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/5) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
(2/5) Updating fontconfig cache...
(3/5) Updating TeXLive filename database...
/usr/bin/mktexlsr: line 148: kpsewhich: command not found
/usr/bin/env: ‘texlua’: No such file or directory
(4/5) Updating TeXLive format files...
Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/fmtutil line 17.
/usr/bin/fmtutil: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/fmtutil line 25.
error: command failed to execute correctly
(5/5) Updating TeXLive font maps...
/usr/bin/mktexlsr: line 148: kpsewhich: command not found
Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/updmap line 22.
/usr/bin/updmap: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/updmap line 28.
error: command failed to execute correctly
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The arch linux maintainer of Texlive messed something up, so I think you need to file a bug report there. Without kpsewhich TeX cannot work because it cannot find its files.